# woocommerce stock price and quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to somehow show the total number of products in stock and the total price of all the products (with the stock number).

Basically I need to write a code that will add all the products and their stock numbers and show me the value of all the products (including those with multiple stock numbers) added together.

Basically I need the price of how much I would sell the products that are in stock at this moment.

Comment: Basically I need the price of how much I would sell the products that are in stock at this moment.

Comment: instead of adding comment to your question, edit your question

Comment: where you stuck, what is your question?

Comment: Run a [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for all products. Loop through the results and add up their stock quantities and their prices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to generally do this: you would have to use a combination of MYSQL, PHP, JQUERY, and AJAX.

You look in your database using jquery + ajax to call mysqli (or other) database. Get the value and append it to your website using jquery.

It is very difficult to suggest any code or a narrow answer without your code.

hope it helps!